# have the content div be always centre aligned no matter what the window size is and regardless of whether the sidebar is there

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a specific layout but don't know how to fix it up in CSS.
here is my code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="outer" style="text-align:center;">      
            <div id="mainContent" style="background-color:red; width:700px; margin-left:130px; 

                    display:inline-block;">
                <p>A Lot of Text Here. Yes, A Lot of Text. Gotta Love it. More Text.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="rightNav" style="background-color:blue; width:130px;                                   display:inline-block;">
                <p>Some Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now the problem is:
I want to have the content div be always centre aligned no matter what the window size is and regardless of whether the sidebar is there. The content is around 700px and the sidebar around 130px. The sidebar needs to sit to the right of the content.

Now I have managed to accomplish the above, but the tricky problem is how can I fix this so that when the window size is say 830px (700+130) that all content is visible and half of the sidebar is not cut off due to the content div being centred.
I hope I have explained this clearly enough.

Update: I have update the code to include CSS. As you can see the red section is centered, the blue to the right. This is what I want, expept when the window gets too small, I always have a minimum of a 130px gap on the left which is not what I want. (but had to put it in there to get the layout aligning right)

Comment: Can you post your css as well?

Comment: Can you show the CSS that you are using right now?  Also, just to be sure, if the window is 830px wide, you want the content div to start at the left, and finish 130px from the right, creating room for the sidebar?  What happens when it is 900 px wide - should there be 35px on each side, or 70px on the left?

Comment: Just to confirm this is still unresoled. Hence no answer marked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears what I want is not possible in a single solution. I will need to use conditional CSS to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this may help

```
<html>
  <body style="overflow:hidden;">
      <div id="mainContent" style="overflow:auto; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; right:130px; bottom:0px;"></div>
      <div id="rightNav" style="overflow:auto; position:absolute; top:0px; width:130px; right:0px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Edited:**
@Nathan Arthur was so kind to add a nice fiddle to demonstrate the solution above.

> ...Demonstration of this in action: [jsfiddle.net/2QQtU](http://jsfiddle.net/2QQtU) Try moving the middle divider to see the magic.

Comment: +1 for Mr. Hartsock! Demonstration of this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/2QQtU/1/ Try moving the middle divider to see the magic.

Comment: An excellent detailed answer, but unfortunatley not what Im after. the content needs to center on the page, regardless of the side bar. In your example the content fills the remaining gap. The content is always fixed at 700px

Comment: Mark, have you tried my solution? I think it's just what you are looking for.

Comment: @SimoneVittori yes I have. Im afraid that doesnt work either.

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
#outer {
   position:relative;
   width:830px;
   margin:0 auto;
}

#content, sidebar {
   float:left;
}    

#content {
   width:700px;
   background-color:#afa;
}

#sidebar {
   width:130px;
   background-color:#faa;
}
```

That's all :)

---

****EDIT**** just added background-colors to see the example better.